# chrome extension popup not open immediately

Tags: google-chrome-extension, browser-action

I'm writing a chrome extension.

When i click the browser action button in the first time - all goes well.

When i click the browser action button the second time, after several minutes of not clicking it, it takes more than 10 seconds until the popup is shown.

I've tried commenting out all of the periodic methods in the background and all of the methods in the load event of the popup, but it still doesn't shown immediately.

any suggestions?

Comment: I believe adding the relevant code snippets would help people help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar issue with the popup when I was adding an iframe to the popup. Chrome would wait with showing the popup until that iframe was loaded.

For me the fix was wrapping the code that added the iframe to the HTML in:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    // Code here
},0);
```

This way Chrome showed the popup first, after which it begin with loading the iframe.

Maybe you have a similar problem?

Answer (score 0):

i have seen this behavior before when you have a long running ajax call that you are doing on popup load.. hard to tell further without code samples or description of what you are doing